# Single Implementation for GET, LIST, ... endpoints for separate proto files

Tags: go, architecture, grpc, rpc

I've worked with RPC in past and from my experience, each RPC service needs separate implementation. for example, consider `protos/oplaccount.proto` has following service:

```
service OplAccountGlobalObjectDefaultService {
    rpc Get(OplAccountGlobalObjectDefaultGetRequest) returns (OplAccountGlobalObjectDefaultGetResponse);
    rpc List(OplAccountGlobalObjectDefaultListRequest) returns (OplAccountGlobalObjectDefaultListResponse);
}
```

and `protos/deliveryaccount.proto` has following service

```
service DelAccountGlobalObjectDefaultService {
    rpc Get(DelAccountGlobalObjectDefaultGetRequest) returns (DelAccountGlobalObjectDefaultGetResponse);
    rpc List(DelAccountGlobalObjectDefaultListRequest) returns (DelAccountGlobalObjectDefaultListResponse);
}
```

When I designed solution to implement it, I'd separate impl for each of these services on client and server side i.e. there's 2 GET impl and 2 LIST impl.(one for each service/proto)

However, it's strongly suggested to have one generic GET implementation for all these different protos (and similarly one for LIST, Search, etc.) and have handler for each proto file calling this single one-time implemented GET/LIST, etc.

**Note:** *We can assume  that all protos file will impl. either GET or LIST or Both with the same signature but different req, res obj.*

My question is:

1. Is it considered good practice in Go?
2. If yes, how it can be done for different protos file given that GET method signature is same but request and response objs. are differnt for each proto. Any example code or link is much appreciated.

Comment: If the request/response objects are different, signatures are different. Even if you have the same implementation on your backend, the server and client need separate methods.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Did you mean signature are same? If not, what about that case. In this case, Suppose `GET` will always have same signature i.e. `GET(req obj) returns (res obj)`. Any link or example code will be great if you've it handy.

Comment: Technically speaking, signature of a function includes its name, the types of its inputs, and the types of its outputs. So two functions with the same name but different types of inputs/outputs have different signatures.